# DevForce 2010 Formatting Dates for EntityQuery

Tags: c#, .net, devforce

I've run into a situation where I need to query by Date and Time.  I'm trying to write an EntityQuery where the date and time are in the same format.  The query below returns no rows.  However if I remove the two date clauses, rows are returned and then I can check the dates looping through the results.  I would prefer to use the dates in the query.

```
the variable ap in the query is a C# object

var query = from log in Manager.Logs
            where log.StartDttm == ap.StartDttm
                  && log.EndDttm == ap.EndDttm
                  && log.TypeId == 1
            select log;
```

I came up with this workaround to query between midnight and 11:59:59pm for each date.  I don't like this either, but this does at least reduce the number of rows returned by the query.

```
var query = from log in Manager.Logs
            where && log.StartDttm >= ap.StartDttmQueryBegin
                  && log.StartDttm <= ap.StartDttmQueryEnd
                  && log.EndDttm >= ap.EndDttmQueryBegin
                  && log.EndDttm <= ap.EndDttmQueryEnd
                  && log.TypeId == 1
            select log;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DevForce doesn't expect any specific date/time formats or modify them when the query is built and executed, but it's not the date format per se but the precision of the data stored in the database vs. the precision of the DateTime fields in the "ap" object which is causing the issue.

In EF you can use the EntityFunctions and/or SQLFunctions APIs to perform date/time truncating/formatting, but these are difficult to use in DevForce due to the client/server serialization and EntityQuery to ObjectQuery conversion that DevForce performs.  These APIs can be made to work on the "server side" of DevForce via an RPC call.

Your workaround, although it may feel cumbersome, is probably your best option.  You could also try calling a stored procedure or using an ESQL passthru query, both of which will give you a little more control over the resulting SQL query.